# Signal handling in multi-threaded Python

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

This should be very simple and I'm very surprised that I haven't been able to find this questions answered already on stackoverflow.

I have a daemon like program that needs to respond to the SIGTERM and SIGINT signals in order to work well with upstart. I read that the best way to do this is to run the main loop of the program in a separate thread from the main thread and let the main thread handle the signals. Then when a signal is received the signal handler should tell the main loop to exit by setting a sentinel flag that is routinely being checked in the main loop.

I've tried doing this but it is not working the way I expected. See the code below:

```
from threading import Thread
import signal
import time
import sys

stop_requested = False    

def sig_handler(signum, frame):
    sys.stdout.write("handling signal: %s\n" % signum)
    sys.stdout.flush()

    global stop_requested
    stop_requested = True    

def run():
    sys.stdout.write("run started\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    while not stop_requested:
        time.sleep(2)

    sys.stdout.write("run exited\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)

t = Thread(target=run)
t.start()
t.join()
sys.stdout.write("join completed\n")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I tested this in the following two ways:

1)

```
$ python main.py > output.txt&
[2] 3204
$ kill -15 3204
```

2)

```
$ python main.py
ctrl+c
```

In both cases I expect this written to the output:

```
run started
handling signal: 15
run exited
join completed
```

In the first case the program exits but all I see is:

```
run started
```

In the second case the SIGTERM signal is seemingly ignored when ctrl+c is pressed and the program doesn't exit.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try replacing `t.join()` with `while t.is_alive(): t.join(1)`.  Your main thread will wake up every second to check for signals.

Comment: More reading: http://snakesthatbite.blogspot.com/2010/09/cpython-threading-interrupting.html

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The problem is that, as explained in [Execution of Python signal handlers](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.html#execution-of-python-signal-handlers):

> A Python signal handler does not get executed inside the low-level (C) signal handler. Instead, the low-level signal handler sets a flag which tells the virtual machine to execute the corresponding Python signal handler at a later point(for example at the next bytecode instruction)
>
> …
>
> A long-running calculation implemented purely in C (such as regular expression matching on a large body of text) may run uninterrupted for an arbitrary amount of time, regardless of any signals received. The Python signal handlers will be called when the calculation finishes.

Your main thread is blocked on `threading.Thread.join`, which ultimately means it's blocked in C on a `pthread_join` call. Of course that's not a "long-running calculation", it's a block on a syscall… but nevertheless, until that call finishes, your signal handler can't run.

And, while on some platforms `pthread_join` will fail with `EINTR` on a signal, on others it won't. On linux, I believe it depends on whether you select BSD-style or default `siginterrupt` behavior, but the default is no.

---

So, what can you do about it?

Well, I'm pretty sure the [changes to signal handling in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#signal) actually changed the default behavior on Linux so you won't need to do anything if you upgrade; just run under 3.3+ and your code will work as you're expecting. At least it does for me with CPython 3.4 on OS X and 3.3 on Linux. (If I'm wrong about this, I'm not sure whether it's a bug in CPython or not, so you may want to raise it on python-list rather than opening an issue…)

On the other hand, pre-3.3, the `signal` module definitely doesn't expose the tools you'd need to fix this problem yourself. So, if you can't upgrade to 3.3, the solution is to wait on something interruptible, like a `Condition` or an `Event`. The child thread notifies the event right before it quits, and the main thread waits on the event before it joins the child thread. This is definitely hacky. And I can't find anything that guarantees it will make a difference; it just happens to work for me in various builds of CPython 2.7 and 3.2 on OS X and 2.6 and 2.7 on Linux…

Comment: "This is definitely hacky" - I wouldn't say that generally. synchronizing your threads on a higher level of abstraction than simply using `join` is sensible. If your goal is to wait for the thread to exit (like this specific example) then `join` is the right tool; if you want to wait for the workload to finish, the a `Condition` etc. makes more sense. The workload could be executed (for example) in a pooled thread that doesn't exit immediately, after all.

Answer (score 12):

abarnert's answer was spot on. I'm still using Python 2.7 however. In order to solve this problem for myself I wrote an InterruptableThread class.

Right now it doesn't allow passing additional arguments to the thread target. Join doesn't accept a timeout parameter either. This is just because I don't need to do that. You can add it if you want. You will probably want to remove the output statements if you use this yourself. They are just there as a way of commenting and testing.

```
import threading
import signal
import sys

class InvalidOperationException(Exception):
    pass    

# noinspection PyClassHasNoInit
class GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler:
    threads = []
    initialized = False

    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler.sig_handler)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler.sig_handler)
        GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler.initialized = True

    @staticmethod
    def add_thread(thread):
        if threading.current_thread().name != 'MainThread':
            raise InvalidOperationException("InterruptableThread objects may only be started from the Main thread.")

        if not GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler.initialized:
            GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler.initialize()

        GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler.threads.append(thread)

    @staticmethod
    def sig_handler(signum, frame):
        sys.stdout.write("handling signal: %s\n" % signum)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        for thread in GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler.threads:
            thread.stop()

        GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler.threads = []    

class InterruptableThread:
    def __init__(self, target=None):
        self.stop_requested = threading.Event()
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=target, args=[self]) if target else threading.Thread(target=self.run)

    def run(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        GlobalInterruptableThreadHandler.add_thread(self)
        self.t.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_requested.set()

    def is_stop_requested(self):
        return self.stop_requested.is_set()

    def join(self):
        try:
            while self.t.is_alive():
                self.t.join(timeout=1)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            self.stop_requested.set()
            self.t.join()

        sys.stdout.write("join completed\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

The class can be used two different ways. You can sub-class InterruptableThread:

```
import time
import sys
from interruptable_thread import InterruptableThread

class Foo(InterruptableThread):
    def __init__(self):
        InterruptableThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        sys.stdout.write("run started\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        while not self.is_stop_requested():
            time.sleep(2)

        sys.stdout.write("run exited\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stdout.write("all exited\n")
sys.stdout.flush()

foo = Foo()
foo2 = Foo()
foo.start()
foo2.start()
foo.join()
foo2.join()
```

Or you can use it more like the way threading.thread works. The run method has to take the InterruptableThread object as a parameter though.

```
import time
import sys
from interruptable_thread import InterruptableThread

def run(t):
    sys.stdout.write("run started\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    while not t.is_stop_requested():
        time.sleep(2)

    sys.stdout.write("run exited\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()

t1 = InterruptableThread(run)
t2 = InterruptableThread(run)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()

sys.stdout.write("all exited\n")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Do with it what you will.

Comment: appreciate the post but Python 2.7 is headed for doom so you might want to reconsider a solution for 3.7

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem here [signal not handled when multiple threads join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673497/signal-not-handled-when-multiple-threads-join). After reading [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert)'s answer, I changed to Python 3 and solved the problem. But I do like to change all my program to python 3. So, I solved my program by avoiding calling thread join() before signal sent. Below is my code.

**It is not very good, but solved my program in python 2.7. My question was marked as duplicated, so I put my solution here.**

```
import threading, signal, time, os


RUNNING = True
threads = []

def monitoring(tid, itemId=None, threshold=None):
    global RUNNING
    while(RUNNING):
        print "PID=", os.getpid(), ";id=", tid
        time.sleep(2)
    print "Thread stopped:", tid


def handler(signum, frame):
    print "Signal is received:" + str(signum)
    global RUNNING
    RUNNING=False
    #global threads

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, handler)

    print "Starting all threads..."
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=monitoring, args=(1,), kwargs={'itemId':'1', 'threshold':60})
    thread1.start()
    threads.append(thread1)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=monitoring, args=(2,), kwargs={'itemId':'2', 'threshold':60})
    thread2.start()
    threads.append(thread2)
    while(RUNNING):
        print "Main program is sleeping."
        time.sleep(30)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    print "All threads stopped."
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows and all except SIGINT are not available on Windows for Python 3.6.