# signal handling in python not working for multi threaded program

Tags: python, multithreading, process, signals

I have a multi threaded program with the flow as below:

### Main program:

```
#Listen to the signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, some_function)

#Actual logic by calling some other function, which spawns multiple threads
try:
   core_logic()  <--- any exception here will invoke the cleanup_function()
except:
   cleanup_function()
```

### some_function code

```
def some_function():
    #kill the states of the sub-threads generated by main core_logic()
    os.kill(processid, sigint)
```

### cleanup code:

```
def cleanup_function():
    #send a kill to the main program using os.getpid()
```

I'm facing problems with the cleanup. When I invoke the main program and when an exception is thrown, the signal is sent correctly and the main program gets the SIGINT, but all the sub-threads are not terminated correctly. What mistake am I doing. Should I use SIGTERM instead? Will that help in killing all the sub-threads and child process spawned?

Comment: What do you mean by "sub-threads are not terminated correctly"?

Comment: The files or directories created by the sub-threads are still in USE and i'm not able to delete them.

Comment: You expect SIGINT to automatically terminate running threads so that they stop running before your cleanup function runs?

Comment: Yes. Because in the some_function() when the signal is listened, I'm iterating through the processes spawned and terminating them using terminate()

Comment: I sense significant confusion here. The question talks about *threads*, but now you are talking about *processes* holding resources. These two --especially in python-- are fundamentally different. If using processes: `terminate()` just signals termination, it does not *wait* for termination. Use `join()` to wait for actual termination.

Comment: Yes. I'm doing it. To be more clear i'm doing process.terminate() and then process.join().

Comment: Please update your question with *all relevant* information. It is obvious that the problem is not adequately described by the information you are currently giving.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673497/signal-not-handled-when-multiple-threads and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676835/signal-handling-in-multi-threaded-python may be helpful