# signal not handled when multiple threads join

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

When I run `kill -SIGUSR1 process_id`, nothing happened. It seems that signal is not received by the main thread. I have been reading lots of posts, but I just need to do a quick fix. How to do a small fix?

```
01 RUNNING = True

58 def monitoring(tid, itemId=None, threshold=None):         
62  global RUNNING 
63  while(RUNNING): 
64      doSomething()
65      time.sleep(2) 

71 def handler(signum, frame): 
72  print "Signal is received:" + str(signum) 
73  global RUNNING 
74  RUNNING=False 


77 if __name__ == '__main__': 
79  signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler) 
80  signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, handler) 
81  signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler) 
82 
85  threads = [] 
86  print "Starting all threads..." 
87  thread1 = threading.Thread(target=monitoring, args=(1,), kwargs={'itemId':'123E', 'threshold':60}) 
88  thread1.start() 
89  threads.append(thread1) 
90  thread2 = threading.Thread(target=monitoring, args=(2,), kwargs={'itemId':'234gE', 'threshold':60}) 
91  thread2.start() 
92  threads.append(thread2)  
95  for thread in threads: 
97      thread.join() 

99  print "All threads stopped."
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Already solved the problem.

(1) 
The first solution is to run it under python 3.3+. There is a good explaination [Signal handling in multi-threaded Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676835/signal-handling-in-multi-threaded-python)

(2) Try to avoid thread join before signal sent:

```
import threading, signal, time, os


RUNNING = True
threads = []

def monitoring(tid, itemId=None, threshold=None):
    global RUNNING
    while(RUNNING):
        print "PID=", os.getpid(), ";id=", tid
        time.sleep(2)
    print "Thread stopped:", tid


def handler(signum, frame):
    print "Signal is received:" + str(signum)
    global RUNNING
    RUNNING=False
    #global threads

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, handler)

    print "Starting all threads..."
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=monitoring, args=(1,), kwargs={'itemId':'1', 'threshold':60})
    thread1.start()
    threads.append(thread1)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=monitoring, args=(2,), kwargs={'itemId':'2', 'threshold':60})
    thread2.start()
    threads.append(thread2)
    while(RUNNING):# Main program blocked here until signal received.
        print "Main program is sleeping."
        time.sleep(30)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    print "All threads stopped."
```