# Systemd not receiving SIGTERM on stop when using threads in program

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, systemd

I want to create a python program which runs as a systemd service. I want to be able to stop it gracefully. I've come across a weird behavior: when I use threads, a python program does not receive a SIGTERM signal on `systemctl stop example.service`, but everything works fine if I do not use threads. The example is following:

**Without threads. (service receives SIGTERM signal and stops as expected):**

```
import signal
import time
import threading
import sys

RUN=True

# catch SIGINT and SIGTERM and stop application
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    global RUN
    print("Got signal: "+str(sig))
    RUN=False
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

# some working thread inside application
def my_thread():
    global RUN
    while RUN:
        print("sleep")
        time.sleep(1.0)

my_thread()
print("Done.")
```

[image: stopping a program without threads works]

**With threads. (program does not receive SIGTERM signal and is forcefully killed by SIGKILL after timeout):**

```
import signal
import time
import threading
import sys

RUN=True

# catch SIGINT and SIGTERM and stop application
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    global RUN
    print("Got signal: "+str(sig))
    RUN=False
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

# some working thread inside application
def my_thread():
    global RUN
    while RUN:
        print("sleep")
        time.sleep(1.0)

# wait for thread to complete and exit
t = threading.Thread(target=my_thread)
t.start()
t.join()
print("Done.")
```

[image: stopping a program with threads does not work]

**Systemd service file:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Example service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /opt/program/main.py
TimeoutSec=60
Restart=on-failure
Type=simple
User=mixo
Group=mixo
```

Just to be clear: my program requires multiple threads so I want to be able to stop service gracefully even if I use threads in my program. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676835/signal-handling-in-multi-threaded-python) is probably relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Shawn who suggested this old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676835/signal-handling-in-multi-threaded-python), I have now solved the problem.

The problem is in how signal handlers are implemented in python. The line `t.join()` is blocking my main thread and therefore no signals can be received. There are 2 simple solutions:

**1) Use python 3.x**

**or 2) Use signal.pause() to wait for signal like this:**

```
import signal
import time
import threading
import sys

RUN=True

# catch SIGINT and SIGTERM and stop application
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    global RUN
    print("Got signal: "+str(sig))
    RUN=False
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

# some working thread inside application
def my_thread():
    global RUN
    while RUN:
        print("sleep")
        time.sleep(1.0)

# wait for thread to complete and exit
t = threading.Thread(target=my_thread)
t.start()
signal.pause()
t.join()
print("Done.")
```